# How to pass variable to a class defined function "pointer"?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to have a class instance attribute being a "pointer" to a function.
I can't figure out how to pass parameters to these functions..?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

def add_two(p1, p2):
    return (p1 + p2)

def multiply_trhee(p1, p2, p3):
    return (p1*p2*p3)

@dataclass
class my_class:
    function: function = None
    return_val: int = None

    def run_function(self):
        self.return_val = self.function(**kwargs) #???

a = my_class(add_two)
b = my_class(multiply_trhee)

a.run_function(p1= 1, p2 = 2)
b.run_function(p1 = 1, p2 = 2, p3 = 3)

print(a.return_val) #should print 3
print(b.return_val) #should print 6
```

Comment: `def run_function` doesn't take any parameters, how do you expect it to be passed parameters then? Likely, you want it to accept `def run_function(self, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

You can accept arbitrary parameters to `run_function` and propagate them as follows:

```
def run_function(self, **kwargs):
    self.return_val = self.function(**kwargs)
```

But you should probably make a more structured class definition:

```
class my_class:

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.function = func

    def run_function(self, **kwargs):
        self.return_val = self.function(**kwargs)
```

Also, it is preferable to directly return the value from functions.

Complete code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

def add_two(p1, p2):
    return (p1 + p2)

def multiply_trhee(p1, p2, p3):
    return (p1*p2*p3)

@dataclass
class my_class:

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.function = func

    def run_function(self, **kwargs):
        return self.function(**kwargs)

a = my_class(add_two)
b = my_class(multiply_trhee)

print(a.run_function(p1= 1, p2 = 2))
print(b.run_function(p1 = 1, p2 = 2, p3 = 3))
```

Comment: return_val should be an instance member not a class member...but function can be a class member.

Comment: Such details depend on your use case; this is a general example. You can modify it as per your needs.

Comment: For minimal change, follow the first block of the answer.